# How to change the font and position of the label using class LegendXYItemLabelGenerator?

Tags: java, class

I would like to change the font and the position because I have noticed overlapping in the bubble chart for bubbles that are closer together. Using your class has helped greatly but I am not sure how to do this.

```
public class LegendXYItemLabelGenerator extends StandardXYItemLabelGenerator
implements XYItemLabelGenerator, Cloneable, PublicCloneable,
  Serializable {
    private LegendItemCollection legendItems;

    public LegendXYItemLabelGenerator(LegendItemCollection legendItems) {
      super();
      this.legendItems = legendItems;
    }

    @Override
    public String generateLabel(XYDataset dataset, int series, int item) {
      LegendItem legendItem = legendItems.get(series);
      return legendItem.getLabel();
    }
}

renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new LegendXYItemLabelGenerator(plot.getLegendItems()));
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In order to change the font, your Renderer would allow such method as setBaseLabelFont: renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(new Font("Arial",Font.ITALIC,8)); This has resolved the font issue and now more flexibility can be had.

Comment: "Using your class" --> that doesn't tell us anything because we don't know whose class you mean.